# ASA static routes

Tags: routing, cisco-asa

I have an Interface (IF1) with `172.16.18.254 255.255.255.0 security Level 0`.

This one connects to a Firwall where the network `172.16.18.0 255.255.255.0` is located and the gateway to this is 172.16.18.1. On this network is a Server with IP `172.16.18.100`. I can ping from the Server the interface on the ASA.

Ping 172.16.18.100 - works.

But from another interface (IF2) on the asa 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 (VLAN 168) Security Level 100. Their is no response when I try to ping the Server 172.16.18.100.

Is their a route needed ?

The other firewall also provides a webseite to login to VPN. 172.16.10.10 is the IP.

Will the route

```
route IF2 172.16.10.10 255.255.255.255 172.16.18.1
```

work ?

the server 172.16.18.100 is able to reach this website. I want the hosts on IF1 also to be able to reach it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

You probably don’t have a route back. The gateway at 172.16.18.1 doesn’t know how to get back to your internal (192.169.1.0) network.

You need a route on that device.

If you can’t modify that device, consider using NAT to hide your internal addresses.

Comment: if you assumed, i currently have no access .. 
I have done NAT, and now I'm able to open the site. The website is an WebPortal of an VPN. Could it be possible, that the login isn't working because of the route back?